# Parsing JSON array of arrays in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm currently using jQuery's `$.get()` to process IDs entered in a text field with a database. It currently works quite well, especially the PHP which can handle multiple comma-separated entries.

The issue I'm having is with jQuery; more specifically, JSON parsing. The PHP file returns an array of arrays, which is used to manipulate a `<table>`. While it works with single entries, i.e. `"12346"`, it doesn't work with multiple entries, such as `"123456,789101"`.

**The error is specifically thrown at Line 77:** `var serverData = $.parseJSON(data)[0];`

Here's the stack trace

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 2
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (myScript.js:77)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Here is what my code looks like so far:

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
//Database access is arbitrary
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { //iterate through db results
  $student_array[$row['sid']] = array(
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'advisory' => $row['advisory']
  );
}

$json_params[] = array(
  "students" => $student_array, /* The array of arrays */
  "success" => "n students were checked in, nice!" /* generic message */
  "failure" => "m students couldn't be accessed"
);

echo json_encode($json_params);
```

jQuery:

```
$.get("check-in.php", {value: inputValue}).done(function(data) {
  var serverData = $.parseJSON(data)[0];
  if (serverData.success) {
    $.each(serverData.students, function(sid, tableValues) {
      /* Create a <tr> based on the information (using the key as the SID,
       * name, and advisory, and insert that <tr> into a table */
    });
  }
}
```

This might be the culprit, which is the JSON text causing the issue:

```
[{
  "students": {
    "245680":{"name":"John Doe","advisory":"9"},
    "135791":{"name":"Jane Smith","advisory":"7"}
  },
  "success":"2 students were checked in!"
}]
```

I'm quite puzzled as it's been working fine with single number entries. I've looked at solutions to "parsing JSON arrays of arrays" on this site, but I've tried all the suggestions for those. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Completely forgot, I'll edit the post

Comment: use console.log to print out the json data and make sure it looks correct  (or better yet, learn how to use the debugger that's built into the browser)

Comment: The JSON string in my post is copied from the console

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the need to make `$json_params` as an array. It is stored outside of looping and executed only once. Just remove `[]` part. THe code will look like this.

```
$json_params = array(
    "students" => $student_array, /* The array of arrays */
    "success" => "n students were checked in, nice!" /* generic message */
    "failure" => "m students couldn't be accessed"
);
```

In your `jQuery`, you can simply retrieve JSON result without having to access key array. `[0]` isn't necessary as `[]` in `$json_params` is removed.

```
var serverData = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Yeah, are you sure you're not getting any kind of Error or Warning in your PHP output? Maybe that's what is messing with the JSON, the response from PHP MUST BE valid JSON from byte 0 to the end.

Comment: yeah, no error or warning in php output. I suspect about the array access in this js code. `$.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: PHP is free of any errors; it does exactly as intended. I'll try this

Comment: PHP looks like this: `$json_params = array(); $json_params["students"] = $success_array; $json_params["success"] = $result_success;` and jQuery looks like this: `var serverData = $.parseJSON(data);`. Issue still persists

Comment: what's the output of `serverData`?

Comment: Same input. No noticeable changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174921/discussion-between-david-and-curtis-upshall).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has this:

```
var serverData = $.parseJSON(data)[0];
```

but it's failing because data is already an object (not a json string that needs to be parsed).
Try this:

```
var serverData = data[0];
```

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: `console.log()` says `serverData.success` is `undefined` :/

Comment: i've tested this (browser side) with your json data and it works.  is it possible that you used console.log incorrectly?

Comment: are you looking at the console output or are you looking at the return value of console.log?

Comment: Correction, `console.log(data)` is what I used to get the JSON string. `console.log(serverData)` shows the Object itself. So I suppose it's not an issue with JSON but with jQuery